# How to get list of mean values of sale for 45 stores

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

```
filt=Q3_df['Store']=1;

Q3_df.loc[filt,'Weekly_Sales'].mean()

# >>>output=1555264.3975524479
```

```
# Q3_df  dataset#
Store   Weekly_Sales
                
  1  1643690.90 
  1  1641957.44 
  1  1611968.17 
  1  1409727.59 
  1  1554806.68 
  ...   ... ... ... 
  45    713173.95   
  45    733455.07
```

Comment: `filt=Q3_df['Store']=1` _assigns `1`_ to both `filt` and `Q3_df['Store']`. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `groupby` aggregation?

```
Q3_df.groupby(Q3_df.index)[['Weekly_Sales']].mean()
```

Just to articulate with a small example:

```
import pandas as pd

Q3_df = pd.DataFrame({"Store":[1,1,2,2,3,3], "Weekly_Sales":list(range(6))})
```

If `Store` is **not** the index:

```
Q3_df.groupby(["Store"])[["Weekly_Sales"]].mean()
```

If `Store` is the index:

```
Q3_df.set_index("Store", inplace=True)

Q3_df.groupby(Q3_df.index)[["Weekly_Sales"]].mean()
```

With this specific example, they both give:

```
       Weekly_Sales
Store
1               0.5
2               2.5
3               4.5
```

If `Store` is the index, you can assign those mean values to a new column:

```
Q3_df.assign(mean_values=Q3_df.groupby(Q3_df.index)[["Weekly_Sales"]].mean())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       Weekly_Sales  mean_values
Store
1                 0          0.5
1                 1          0.5
2                 2          2.5
2                 3          2.5
3                 4          4.5
3                 5          4.5
```

Comment: yes ,but here my index is set to store ..so cant perform group by on index

Comment: how can i rename the column as mean weekly sales for new generated data frame?

Comment: @FAISALBARGI you should use the method rename : Q3_df.rename(columns={'Weekly_Sales': 'mean_weekly_sales'})

Take a look to this for more information : 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html